# Question with asymptote with function

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

I have a function
$$\frac{x}{x^2+1}$$
and have determined the horizontal asymptote to be $y = 0$ because the denominator has the highest degree. However when I graph this function $y$ is $0$ at the origin. Both the left and right hand side of the graph do have the asymptote. Why does the asymptote not respected at the origin?

Comment: Horizontal asymptotes are *only* in reference to the *end* behavior of the curve... what happens as $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to -\infty}f(x)$.  Whatever happens in the middle is completely irrelevant.